Need help to tally the numbers, doing match off against different contract and solve decimals problem
I am trying to use python to help me to match off Sales & Purchase contract against the actual Collection & Deliveries of goods. The size of the S&P contracts are different from the actual C&D of goods hence to manually match it off can be tedious as factor like product type, buyer and supplier info, price, contract months need to match. So i have faced two problems now.

First, the already matched off contract (eg: initial size 10 metric tons, I have matched it off previously and turn the net position to 0) still get matched more than once.

As per the image you can see contract number 30831 had been matched, the total size is 6.17, so by right it shouldn't match again.

The number is correct up to the decimal point, but the digits after the decimal are often incorrect.


Here is the code. let me know which part I should amend.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CjJdIhertbNeDF4qBEzD6_9nrHnJvKzF/view?usp=sharing

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Welcome to SO. Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Post them as text instead. Information unnecessarily posted as image is considered missing debugging details.

Note that all relevant detail (code, sample data, etc) needs to be here in your question, not as a link to an external site.

This might be a pointer towards a solution, based on fictional data with many duplicate amounts.
# Note that these two modules are imported
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

Imagine that you have a dataframe (df) of Accts with Date due and Due amount
    Date due  Acct  Due
 0 2024-01-01  1001  100
 1 2024-02-01  1001  100
 2 2024-03-01  1001  100
 3 2024-04-01  1001  100
 4 2024-05-01  1001  100
 5 2024-01-01  1002   90
 6 2024-02-01  1002   90
 7 2024-03-01  1002   90
 8 2024-04-01  1002   90
 9 2024-05-01  1002   90

And a dataframe (df1) where orders have been settled
    Date       Acct    Settled
 0 2024-01-15  1001      100
 1 2024-02-15  1001      100
 2 2024-03-15  1001      100
 3 2024-04-15  1001      100
 4 2024-01-03  1002      120
 5 2024-02-03  1002      120
 6 2024-03-03  1002      120
 7 2024-04-03  1002      120

Option 1 (to get balance at Acct level):
df_sum = df.groupby(["Acct"]).sum().reset_index()
df1_sum = df1.groupby(["Acct"]).sum().reset_index()
df_sum = df_sum.merge(df1_sum, left_on = ["Acct"], right_on = ["Acct"], how = 'left')
df_sum["Bal"] = df_sum["Due"] - df_sum["Settled"]
df_sum

    Acct    Due Settled Bal
0   1001    500 400     100
1   1002    450 480     -30

Option 2: to get balance at transaction level
df['CS'] = df.groupby(['Acct'])['Due'].cumsum()
df = df.merge(df1_sum, left_on = ["Acct"], right_on = ["Acct"], how = 'left')
df["LineSettled"] = np.where(df["CS"] <= df["Settled"], "Y", "N")
df

    Date due    Acct    Due CS  Settled LineSettled
0   2024-01-01  1001    100 100 400      Y
1   2024-02-01  1001    100 200 400      Y
2   2024-03-01  1001    100 300 400      Y
3   2024-04-01  1001    100 400 400      Y
4   2024-05-01  1001    100 500 400      N
5   2024-01-01  1002    90  90  480      Y
6   2024-02-01  1002    90  180 480      Y
7   2024-03-01  1002    90  270 480      Y
8   2024-04-01  1002    90  360 480      Y
9   2024-05-01  1002    90  450 480      Y


The OP has not presented any code, data, etc in the question, nor have they provided any specific debugging detail. Please don't answer off-topic questions.
